# Do I need to use a pointer in this situation, when trying to update a variable from a separate class?

Tags: c++

So my program is intended to accept input from the user to create an object with several attributes(variables) and those objects are put into vector. I'm having a particular issue with being able to change the quantity of a particular item in question. It remains unchanged regardless of how many times I call the function from main.cpp.

```
class ClassA {
    public:
        void SetQuantity(int quantityToGet);
        ...
    private:
        int itemQuantity;
        ...
};

void ClassA::SetQuantity(int quantityToGet) {
    itemQuantity = quantityToGet;
}

class ClassB {
    public:
        ClassB();
        void UpdateItemQnty();
        int FindItemLoc(string targetItem);
        ...
    private:
        vector<ClassB> itemsInVector;
        ...
};

    void ClassB::UpdateItemQnty() {
        ClassA currItem;
        string targetName;
        int newQuantity;
        int itemLoc = -1;

        cout << "Enter the item name: ";
        getline(cin, targetName);
        itemLoc = FindItemLoc(targetName);

        cout << "Enter the new quantity: ";
        cin >> newQuantity;
        cin.ignore();

        if (itemLoc > -1) {
            currItem = itemsInVector.at(itemLoc);
            currItem.SetQuantity(newQuantity);   // FIXME (???)
        }
        else {
            cout << "Item not found in vector. Nothing modified." << endl;
        }
    }
```

I'm not getting any errors and the functions I didn't mention or show definition/declarations for, all work properly. I think I need to use a pointer, but I'm not sure how.

- I'll likely delete this after I receive an answer based on the response

Thank You

Comment: As a general rule, please don't delete things after they are answered. That isn't nice to the people who did take time to help you, as they don't retain reputation for their great answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two strange things in your code:

- Your are assigning a ClassA object with ClassB object (above the call of setQuantity). That should give an error, but I guess you made a typo in your post...
- when retrieving the data from the list, your are copying it to the local variable currItem! Hence you are only changing a local copy, not the data in the list.

Declaring currItem as a reference would do the trick in this case, but the declaration of a reference object requires an assignment:

```
ClassA &currItem = itemsInVector.at(itemLoc);
currItem.SetQuantity(newQuantity);
```

Comment: Thank you, I did copy my code wrong. In my actual file, the class object is correctly assigned. I definitely need to understand pointers and references better, any suggestions for that would be further appreciated.

Comment: Memory management is a science itself and needs to be studied. I am not an expert myself and I would recommend to study and do some tutorials.

To begin with, you need to know the difference between stack and heap, and which variables you need handle for allocation and deletion.
To make it short:

* Stack memory is limited but fast, while heap memory is "limitless" and slow.

* Heap memory needs to be manually allocated and freed.

* Pointers is pointing to a memory adress, which can either be on stack or heap

* You can never be sure if data on the memory adress is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

You're simply setting the temporary variable's value. Try this,

```
itemsInVector[itemLoc].SetQuantity(newQuantity);
```